# Optional route parameter that must equal a string

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, routes, laravel-5

I need to show the exact same page/data for two differents paths (`/` and `/index`). How can I create a route that satisfies this rule?

I tried the following, but the optional parameter allows for *any* word (like `/hello`, `/world`, or `/anything`), whereas I just want `/` or `/index`:

```
Route::get('/{trending?}', array('as' => 'index', function()
{
    // some code
});
```

Comment: Your tags are ambiguous. Are you using Laravel 4 or 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a regular expression for route parameters, in your case that would look like this:

```
Route::get('/{trending?}', array('as' => 'index', function()
{
    // some code
}))->where('trending', 'index');
```

However if you have a controller anyways (and you probably should) then I'd just add two routes:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'SomeController@index']);
Route::get('index', 'SomeController@index');
```